# NullPointerException, can't figure out way

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

My code is linked here. its kinda a lot and it's my first Java program outside of school projects. so its a little messy. sorry!

I highlighted the parts I'm having trouble with. 
So I create a profile and then when I change the combobox selection (should I use ComboBoxItemStateChanged, or ComboBoxActionPreformed for this?) after adding 2 profiles I get a null pointer exception on the first profile at index 0

ctr F to profileComboBoxItemStateChanged and read the troubleshooting printout I did. and addProfileConfirmActionPerformed is where a profile is being created/added I have a feeling the issue is in there somewhere.

UI/main class: http://pastebin.com/XyGWeXgq
Profile Class: http://pastebin.com/WrpiSCav

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21266037/edit).  Few people will follow external links, and they go stale.  Be sure to use code formatting for the code.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Comment: Oh, and people also aren't going to help find errors in a class of ***1198 lines of code.***  You need to narrow it down.  A lot.

Comment: You could at least attach call stack, people can give you hints just from it.

Comment: Also known as "reading the stack trace for you".  Better to look at it yourself and delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to click on any links, but I can tell you that the stack trace tells you the .java source file and line number at which the NPE is thrown.  You should open that .java source file, navigate to that line number, and look at each object reference dereferenced on that line.  One of them is null.

If you have some skill, open the code in an IDE with a debugger, set a breakpoint at that line in that source file, and step through the code until you hit that line.  Then let the IDE tell you which of the objects is null.

Once you have that, see why you didn't initialize it properly.

This is one of the easiest exceptions to fix.

Comment: thank you. figured it out. i was trying to expand the array and it was wiping it....duh... i figured it out by debugging though. Didnt know how to do that thank you!